# 3DS Max Length/Height flipped?

Tags: 3ds-max

It's been a few months since I've done any modeling in 3DS Max 2010. When I went to create an object, I noticed something funky about the definition for Length/Width/Height parameters on the right...

[image]

I am honestly confused by this. If I remember correctly:

- Length should coordinate with the X-axis.
- Width should coordinate with the Y-axis.
- Height should coordinate with the Z-axis.

Am I thinking wrong or is there something going on here?

Comment: X = Width, Y = Height, Z = Depth. There's no "length".

Comment: I am referring to the parameters on the right side of the image, should have been clearer on that.

Answer (score 1):

Yeap, they are.
It's due legacy. Since for compatibility with old versions it can't be changed in new one it stays so for ages.

But there some Buts:

- Each object have a 'pivot' that 'holds' axes and it can be rotated in any way independently from object itself
- Even pivot's axes are 'imaginary', they're created for usability
- Box is a scripted object, i.e. length is only 'label' of Y axis measure, 99% of modelling time You will no have such values as 'length' (at least I had no for 10 years)

To view local axes switch 'view' on 'local' (dropdown that seen on screenshot).

To move, rotate, scale pivot go Hierarchy tab > Affect Pivot only

Comment: Thanks for the info on the pivot, I'll look into that when I get on the machine tomorrow. Any ideas as to why creating the new box causes the Length to affect Height and Vise-Versa in the properties pane? I realize that as soon as I convert it to geometry it will be of moot point, but I was expecting to approximate values as I'm used to, now I'm confused as to why sometimes I have to figure out which properties mean which coordinates.